# AWS Cognito Revoke federation login

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, apple-id

Our React native application is currently using AWS cognito (with amplify) to authenticate our users. This login allow user to use "Sign with Apple" (and also FB and Google)

We recently get an alert from Apple that indicate that we must provide a way to Delete a user account.

Our app already allow users to delete user data on our side (in our DB) and delete the cognito Account but we also need to revoke Federation link from Cognito to Apple (and other providers by the way)

Is there a way to do that using Amplify or should we handle this "by hand" (calling Apple REST API to revoke the link)

I'm not sure that deleting user from Cognito using Amplify will also send a revoke request to Appel API.
(I didn't find anything in the Amplify/Cognito documentation about this)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @FredPonch - did you find a solution to this? We're facing the same predicament.

Comment: @Kohanz unfortunately not. We decided to switch to another identity service : Auth0, more powerful, more features, more external provider supported, easier to implement and configure, and still free for less than 7000 monthly active users.